# Correct MySQL Syntax for this trigger?

Tags: mysql

Trying to create a simple trigger that after a table update, it checks if a count (InvalidLogins) is over 4, and if so, sets the field 'LockedOut' to 1. Below is how I am attempting to create the trigger, this is my first trigger for MySQL though and I can't get it to work.

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_user_lockout after update ON members
FOR EACH ROW SET LockedOut = 1 where invalidLogins < 4
```

The error that MySQL returns is:
Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.LockedOut = 1 where invalidLogins < 4' at line 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
delimiter |
CREATE TRIGGER update_user_lockout before update ON members
FOR EACH ROW 
    IF NEW.invalidLogins < 4 THEN
        SET NEW.LockedOut = 1;
    END IF;
END
|
delimiter ;
```

- The current record can be referenced with `NEW`
- Choose another delimiter than `;`. Otherwise the trigger definition will end at the first `;` which is too early
- Use a `before` trigger to change values before updating

Comment: This worked after spelling delimiter correctly in the script you wrote :-D Thank you! Will accept your answer in ~ 2 mins.